# CSS positioning not working on Safari

Tags: css, safari

As seen on [THIS LIVE DEMO](http://germanalvarez.net/5/laboratory4.html), when opened from latest Safari version, `.contentPanel` does not apply any animation on load, and neither uses correct posisitoning rules.

This is not properly an animation, its just an `.addClass` jQuery method positioning it from its initial position:

```
.contentPanel,.headerLogo,.subheader{
-webkit-transform:translateX(100vw);
        transform:translateX(100vw);}
```

To its normal position:

```
.expanded{
-webkit-transform:translate(0%);
        transform:translate(0%);}
```

It does not apply neither its top positioning... I have tried also changing vw measure units to percents, with no positive result.

When opened form Chrome/Opera/FF/IE11 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

At least, problem was that Safari for Win is out of date and not releasing new versions since years ago. Last one did not have support for CSS calc(), neither -webkit-calc(), that was the problem.